How to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A^2+B^2)=n$?
We are given two real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $$(AB+BA-A^2-I)^2=AB^2-B^2A\tag{$\ast$}$$
How to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A^2+B^2)=n$? If we substitute $A=B=I$ then $(*)$ is satisfied and the claim follows, but I don't know what approach should I take in general case. I know that $AB^2=B^2A$ must follows from $(*)$, but I couldn't prove that either. I tried to find the exact expression for $(A^2+B^2)^{-1}$ via $(*)$ to prove it is non-degenerate, but I couldn't. It must be proven that $AB+BA-A^2-I=0$ and that assumption det$(A^2+B^2)=0$ leads to a contradiction and also that kerA $\cap$ kerB contains non-zero vector(these are the hints given in published problems list)

Where does this problem come from? An on-going contest?

@user1551 no, this problem came from mathematical olympiad in RUDN university in Moscow that was held in 2023, but there are no sulotions published

@user1551 yes, the matrices are real

It is worth noting that the statement is even false over the complex numbers, for one can consider all pairs of two complex numbers $a,b$ such that $2ab = a^2 + 1$ and find solutions to the equation $a^2 + b^2 = 0$

@user1551 it is done

Now that $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric, the problem becomes very easy to solve.
Let $S=AB+BA-A^2-I$. Then $\|S\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(S^TS)=\operatorname{tr}(S^2)=\operatorname{tr}(AB^2-B^2A)=0$. Therefore $S=0$, i.e., $AB+BA-A^2=I$.
Now pick any $x\in\ker(A^2+B^2)$. Then $0=x^T(A^2+B^2)x=\|Ax\|_2^2+\|Bx\|_2^2$. Hence $Ax=Bx=0$. Consequently, $x=Ix=(AB+BA-A^2)x=0$, meaning that $\ker(A^2+B^2)=0$, or equivalently $\operatorname{rank}(A^2+B^2)=n$.
Edit. As shown in Bruno’s (now deleted) answer, there is actually no need to prove that $S=0$: since $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric, $\ker(A^2+B^2)=\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)$. So, if $x\in\ker(A^2+B^2)$, then
\begin{align}
x&=\left[I+(AB^2-B^2A)-(AB+BA-A^2-I)^2\right]x\\
&=\left[(\cdots)A+(\cdots)B\right]x
\quad\text{(because the two $I$s above cancel out each other)}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Therefore $\ker(A^2+B^2)=0$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A^2+B^2)=n$.
